# standard-version changeLog generation problem with pathspec

Tags: node.js, git, npm, versioning, changelog

I've tried to install it locally `yarn add -D standard-version` [package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/standard-changelog) and use it  for `release versioning` and `changeLog.md` generation, But when I run `yarn release` which is `standard-version`, it will generate changeLog and does the version updating, but there are two problems:

1. `error: pathspec 'CHANGELOG.md' did not match any file(s) known to git`

```sh
λ yarn release
yarn run v1.17.3
$ standard-version
√ bumping version in package.json from 0.6.3 to 0.6.4
√ outputting changes to CHANGELOG.md
√ committing package.json and CHANGELOG.md
error: pathspec 'CHANGELOG.md' did not match any file(s) known to git

Command failed: git commit CHANGELOG.md package.json -m chore(release): 0.6.4
error: pathspec 'CHANGELOG.md' did not match any file(s) known to git

error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

2. repeating previous release commit messages in the new release changelog

What is the problem and how should I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

1. You should change your file `changelog.md` to `CHANGELOG.md`, the issue related to naming convention
2. I had searched this issue for a while and currently I don't see any solutions so far. My current approach is to replace new content with old content in the file. Hope it helps.